# Is it possible to run maven plugin from java class?

Tags: java, plugins, maven

Need to run maven jaxb2 plugin from my app, at run-time. Is it possible?

Comment: In software everything is possible. Care to provide some details?

Comment: Why do you want to run the maven plugin? I suspect you need something related to JAXB done? Then directly use the JAXB API. I am  sure it is possible, but will need a lot of work to get it working. The plugin wont be able to run in isolation, it will need Maven environment and most importantly a pom.xml

Comment: @maksimov In fact, in software everything is Not Possible ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe i have done something that could help you:

```
/**
 * @author swoeste
 * 
 */
public class MavenExecutor {

private final File       configuration;
private final ClassWorld classWorld;

/**
 * Constructor for a new maven executor.
 * 
 * @param aConfiguration
 */
public MavenExecutor( final File aConfiguration ) {
    this.configuration = aConfiguration;
    this.classWorld = new ClassWorld( "plexus.core", this.getClass().getClassLoader() ); //$NON-NLS-1$
}

/**
 * This method is used to perform a mvn  command on the given pom. The original
 * command must be given, also the sub folder and the marker folder in the working directory. The working directory
 * and the configuration file will be added before execution.
 * 
 * @param cmd the mvn command to execute
 * @param pom the absolute path to a maven pom file
 * @param output the absolute path to the working directory
 * @param folder the output sub folder of the working directory
 * @param marker the marker sub folder of the working directory
 * @return
 */
public int unpack( final String cmd, final File pom, final File output, final String folder, final String marker ) {
    final List<String> commands = new ArrayList<String>( //
            Arrays.asList( cmd.split( ConfigurationConstants.MAVEN_DELIMITER ) ) );
    commands.add( "-DoutputDirectory=" + output.getAbsolutePath() + folder ); //$NON-NLS-1$
    commands.add( "-DmarkersDirectory=" + output.getAbsolutePath() + marker ); //$NON-NLS-1$
    commands.add( "-gs=\"" + this.configuration.getAbsolutePath() + "\"" ); //$NON-NLS-1$//$NON-NLS-2$
    commands.add( "-f=\"" + pom.getAbsolutePath() + "\"" ); //$NON-NLS-1$ //$NON-NLS-2$
    return MavenCli.doMain( commands.toArray( new String[commands.size()] ), this.classWorld );
}
```

}

I dont know what exactly you want to do, but if you want to execute a maven plugin on a maven project the above code will work. In my case i execute a mvn dependency:unpack-dependencies command on a project.

To get the above working you need this dependency:

```
  <dependency>
     <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
     <artifactId>maven-embedder</artifactId>
     <version>3.0.3</version>
  </dependency>
```

PS: A good resource for information about how to execute maven things from java is the implementation of the m2eclipse plugin ;)

Answer (score 0):

I you really need that, of course you can. Just download sources of the plugin and look inside what's going on there. You can instantiate a proper Mojo (class that implements plugin's goal) and execute it. However, usually plugins' goals depend heavily on Maven project context that might be really hard to provide (or even mock somehow) so Mojo was able to execute without errors.

I don't know your specific situation, but I'm 99% sure that it would be really more sensible to write own implementation of something you want to achieve, potentially based on stuff you found in the plugin's source code (to not write everything on your own).